# Python multithreading.Process Lock

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to understand the Lock Object in Python. For this, I have programmed, something like the python multithreading.Pool object. However I'm still a bit wondering why the lock don't really seem to lock the execution of the other Processes. If I replace class DoSomething(multiprocessing.Process): by class DoSomething(threading.Thread): this works perfectly (yeah, ok, only if there's no exception, because pop don't work on an empty list); but I'm not sure, wheather this is because of the lock, or because of the shared memory.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing, threading

lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

class DoSomething(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, jobList, lock):
        super(DoSomething, self).__init__()
        self.jobList, self.lock = jobList, lock

    def run(self):

        while jobList != []:               # while there're still jobs available
            self.lock.acquire()            # lock the jobList
            job = self.jobList.pop()       # and take the next job (in fact, pop removes the
            print job                      # lst object from the list and returns it).
            self.lock.release()            # release the jobList, so that another thread may do another job
            # do something with this job ...

threads = []
jobList = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(4):
    threads.append(DoSomething(jobList, lock))
    threads[-1].start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

The output of this program is:

```
$ python multThread.py 
4
3
2
1
4          // so it don't lock, we have calculated the job twice here!
3
2
1
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock is working. The *problem* is that, with multiprocessing, the `jobList` is not in shared memory like it is with threading. In multiprocessing, the separate processes have a copy of the `jobList`. Try making the `jobList` a [multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array). See [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for more info.

Comment: I should have thought of that. Changing the list to manager = multiprocessing.Manager() and jobList = manager.list() works too; Thanks